# Connect to Teradata DB via Postgres

Tags: postgresql, teradata

I need to have access to one table stored in Teradata from Postgres.

Is there any way to connect to Teradata DB from Postgres DB?

I know that I can use export/import functions or create simple ETL process loading data from Teradata to Postgres DB with Talend for example but before I will start I want to be sure that direct linking is not possible (at least I didn't found solution for that on the internet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) (FDW) for Teradata.

[The PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Main_Page) has [the authoritative collection](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fdw) of available FDWs. There is currently no FDW for Teradata.

You have two options:

- Use one of the generic FDW (ODBC or JDBC). I don't know if they are in a working condition.
- Write your own.
  You can either take the hard road and [write one in C](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fdwhandler.html), or you can use [Multicorn](http://multicorn.org/) to write it in Python, which is much easier.